# Loop function to calculate the mean and standard deviation

Tags: r

```
install.packages("quantregGrowth")
library(quantregGrowth)
data(growthData)    #load data
fit<-gcrq(y~ps(x, lambda=seq(0,100,l=20)), tau=c(0.025,0.975),n.boot=10, 
data=growthData)
fit$boot.coef
```

the results is something like this:

```
, , 1

            [,1]       [,2]
 [1,] -25.893935 -25.893835
 [2,]   2.031909   2.032009
...

, , 2

             [,1]        [,2]
 [1,] -0.09662335 -0.09652335
 [2,]  0.51026535  0.51036535
....

, , 10

            [,1]       [,2]
 [1,]  0.3677403  0.3678403
 [2,]  0.3677403  1.4858461
....
```

I want to calculate the Bootstrap confidence interval so I need to get the average between all [,1][,1] elements, then average between [,1][,2], then average between [,2][,1], finally between [,2][,2]. How can how write a loop function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have correctly understood your problem.
Anyway, try this:

```
dms <- dim(fit$boot.coef)
myfun <- function(i,j) mean(fit$boot.coef[i,j,])
outer(1:dms[1], 1:dms[2], FUN=Vectorize(myfun))
```